# Matlab code to generate images from entropy

Tags: matlab, entropy

Could you please help me with this question:

Assume that on average in binary images, 75% of the pixels are white, and 25% are black. What is the entropy of this source? **Model this source in Matlab and generate some sample images according to this process**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29), you just need to apply the definition:

```
H = -0.25 * log2(0.25) - 0.75 * log2(0.75)
```

Since we are using `log2`, the result will be in bits.

As for generating a Matlab B&W (*i.e.* binary) image of size 512x512, you can simply do:

```
im = rand(512) < 0.75;
```

By convention, `true` = 1 = *white* and `false` = 0 = *black*.